# Finding average value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find the minimum, maximum and average value in a number array:

I have the following code below:

```
$number = array(15,20,100,10,25,30);

for ($i=0; $i<count($number); $i++){
    //Find maximum number by max function.
    if ($number[$i] == max($number)){
        //Print maximum number.
        $max = $number[$i];
    }

    //Find minimum number by min function.
    elseif ($number[$i] == min($number)) {
    //Print minimum  number.
        $min = $number[$i];
    }
    //Find the average 
    else ($number[$i] == avg($number)){
    //Print average number
        $avg =$number[$i];
    }

}

echo "min value is $min <br/>";
echo "max value is $max <br/>";
echo "average value is $avg </br>";
```

It seems to be giving me a syntax error on the average part. Please kindly help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Why are you looping over the array?  `min()` and `max()` will just return you the value, no need to loop.  Also, PHP does not have an `avg()` function, might that be the error you are seeing?

Comment: You don't get to invent functions. There's no such thing as `avg()` so you will need to write it.

Answer (score 7):

Your `for` loop is counterproductive here. You're already using almost all the built-in functions you need to get the values you want, but with the `for` loop, you're using them many more times than necessary. All you need is:

```
$max = max($number);
$min = min($number);
$avg = array_sum($number) / count($number);
```

Comment: nice... very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, there's no inherent `avg()` function, but you can get the average easily.  Sum up the total as you loop through:

```php
$total = $total + $number[$i];
```

then divide by the number of values:

```php
$avg = $total / count($number);
```